# Open a wav file to read data in text editor vs in sndfile

Tags: c, wav, textpad

I want to read the data of an 8bit wav file using textPad, I know that the data is located at the 44/46th byte, but I am having problems reading it.

I have that code:

52 49 46 46 F8 37 01 00 57 41 56 45 66 6D 74 20
12 00 00 00 06 00 01 00 40 1F 00 00 40 1F 00 00
01 00 08 00 00 00 66 61 63 74 04 00 00 00 **C6 37

01 00 64 61 74 61 C6 37 01 00 D6 D4 56 54 D5 56

56 51 D4 D3 D0 D6 54 57 D4 54 57 51 57 D0 D3 D1**
etc.

The part in bold is the data of it.

The problem is when i read it in sndfile using `sf_read_int` I get in the buffer the following values:

```
3670016  1572864  -3670016   -1572864   524288   -3670016   -3670016
```

etc

How am I supposed to read the data in the wav file? What is the equation or 'relationship' between the numbers i got in sndfile and the data in textPad?

Oh and one more thing, if i switch the reading to `sf_read_float` instead of int i get values between -0.0001 and +0.0001...

Any idea what's happening, the writing and data processing is very good but I don't understand what's up with these values.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm assuming when you say "in textPad", you have a hex editor plugin? (or textPad has a hex editor built in)

Comment: Yes it does have hex editor built in..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so i found out that the wav file is encoded and libsndfile takes care of it without any intervention. That caused the "unequal" values.

Answer (score 1):

You have some pattern to see in a .wav file:

- "RIFF" : `0x52 0x49 0x46 0x46`
- "WAVE" : `0x57 0x41 0x56 0x45`
- "fmt " : `0x66 0x6d 0x74 0x20`
- "data" : `0x64 0x61 0x74 0x61`

We see `64 61 74 61` at offset **50**. So data begins only at offset 54 and not 46.

You can find a [wave specification](http://www-mmsp.ece.mcgill.ca/Documents/AudioFormats/WAVE/WAVE.html) to understand how is encoded your file.

Thanks to this spec, I can tell you that your file is encoded in ["8-bit ITU-T G.711 A-law"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G.711).

Comment: if it is encoded in 8-bit ITU-T what does that mean?

Comment: and okay let's say it's at 54, then the first bytes are C6 37 01 00 
how can they be interpreted as 3670016  1572864  -3670016 by sf_read_int